# Getting annotation of enum value

Tags: kotlin, enums, annotations

I know how to get an annotation of an enum value in Java.
However Kotlin has its own reflection library and I feel there should be a better way to do the job.
Could please anybody post an example.

Just to be specific let's define an enum class

```kotlin
enum class Enum {
    @SerialName("constant")
    Constant
}
```

I need a function `f(e: Enum): String` so that `f(Enum.Constant) == "constant"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did only a little research here, but it appears there isn't support for this in the Kotlin reflection library. In fact, I discovered the linter doesn't even correctly suggest an annotation target of `FIELD` for your annotation if you give it one that doesn't work for Enum values, and instead incorrectly offers to automatically add a target of `CLASS`.

The problem is that Enum values are basically static member fields, which don't exist in Kotlin except in Enum classes. And the reflection classes don't seem to provide a way to access this special case.

I am struggling however to come up with a use case for Enum value annotations that can't be solved using properties in the Enum constructor(s).

```
enum class MyEnum(val someConstant: String? = null) {
    SomeValue("myConstant")
}
```

Comment: The question provides a use case (using the kotlinx serialisation framework for enums). The following code does not compile at time of writing 
```
@Serializable
enum class Enum(val serialName: String) {
    @SerialName(serialName)
    Constant("constant")
}
```

Comment: @tonicsoft I said a use case that “can’t be solved using properties”. You can serialize and deserialize enums without annotations. You can attach your alternative to annotation metadata to each of the enum values by giving them properties.

Comment: A valid use case is when you want to make an enum `@Deprecated`

Answer (score 10):

You can use a similar approach with java by getting the field by name and then reaching out to the annotation using annotation class.

So if you have below enum and annotation class definitions;

```
enum class Enum {
 @SerialName("constant")
 Constant
}

annotation class SerialName(val value: String)
```

Then you can define the below function and call it as shown below;

```
fun getAnnotationValue(enum:Enum):String = enum.declaringClass.getField(enum.name).getAnnotation(SerialName::class.java).value

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
 println(getAnnotationValue(Enum.Constant))
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `enum.declaringClass` is deprecated, now need to use `enum.declaringJavaClass`